# Calculating multiple polygon areas coverage within multiple polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have shapefiles for school attendance zones (SAZs) and Census Tracts (CTs), where the red lines below are CTs and the lighter lines are SAZs. I would like to calculate the proportion (%) of each CT covered by each SAZ. For example, if one CT was covered by two SAZs (SAZ1 and SAZ2), I want to be able to estimate that 28% of the CT is covered by SAZ1 and 72% of it is covered by SAZ2.

I have not tried anything yet, since I am fairly new at this and cannot think of a solution. I think I would start out by calculating the areas of each polygon in sq. miles, ft, meters, etc., then do a join of some sort (union? intersect?), but I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the community tour here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  and edit your question to include additional details, such as what you have tried, text of any errors you have received, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.

In a simple example, if you have 3 different polygons:

[image]

You can make a union or an intersect, in this case, a union:

[image]

After this, calculate area with **Field calculator**. The output unit, in this case, is in meters, because I'm working with UTM projection:

[image]

You can make dynamic tables with **GroupStats** plugin:

[image]

Or, you can save shapefile as .csv file or copy/paste observations to a spreadsheet and create a pivot table to determine percent of one area over other:

[image]

If "layer_1" is your objective layer, you can save pivot table as .csv file, open it in QGis and join it to the layer in Properties window / Joins.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to do this and let you know how successful I am at it!